# How to add multiple hostnames and pathnames in Next.js config file for images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I tried to import multiple image from different hostname for `next/image`. I tried this in `next.confiq.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: ['i.ibb.co', 'https://www.pexels.com/'],
        port: '',
        pathname: [
          '/x59q5zG/2560px-Airbnb-Logo-BC3-A9lo-svg.png',
          'search/travel/?orientation=landscape',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Single image from single hostname and pathname is ok. But when I tried multilple it says:

```
Server Error
Error: Invalid src prop (https://i.ibb.co/x59q5zG/2560px-Airbnb-Logo-BC3-A9lo-svg.png) on `next/image`, hostname "i.ibb.co" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

Comment: Hi Mubasshir! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to transform `hostname` to an array. Instead use multiple objects, one per domain, inside `remotePatterns`, as an example, like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "i.ibb.co",
        // ...
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "https://www.pexels.com/",
        // ...
      },
    ],
  },
};
```